# What exactly does 'npm install -g ' do?

Tags: node.js, npm, sinopia

I want to set up a private npm registry using sinopia and I executed `npm install -g sinopia`, but some error message occurred:

```
> crypt3@0.1.8 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sinopia/node_modules/crypt3
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.node-gyp/4.2.3"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sinopia/node_modules/crypt3/.node-gyp"
make: Entering directory `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sinopia/node_modules/crypt3/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/crypt3/crypt3.o
In file included from ../crypt3.cc:7:0:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:261:25: error: redefinition of âtemplate<class T> v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T>)â
 NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T> val) {
                         ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:256:25: error: âtemplate<class T> v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T>)â previously declared here
 NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T> val) {
                         ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:661:13: error: ânode::smallocâ has not been declared
     , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
             ^
```

I can see the `.h` files which relate to C or C++; how come this happens? All the stuff [I found](https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia) within sinopia is about JavaScript.

What does `npm install` do? In my opinion, it should only initiate some download process.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`npm install <package>` or `npm install -g <package>` will

1. Download an npm package you specify with the  argument, or inside your package.json file, along with its dependencies (from the npm repository host you define) inside a node_modules folder. (Or use an already existing local copy of it. see [shrink-wrapping](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap))
2. Run the `pre-install`, `install` and `post-install` scripts for itself and each of its dependencies. See [Lifecycle Scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)
3. The -g directive tells npm to install the package in the global shared node_modules folder (usually where node is). This will also allow you to access the module from the command-line, as the bin is symlinked into a PATH folder (usually usr/local/bin). Check this [link](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders)

In the case of sinopia, they do not have a standard `package.json` file, they have a package.yaml file. Check the [`yamp` plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yapm).

If you check their pre-publish script, it contains

```
prepublish: js-yaml package.yaml > package.json
```

Which converts their package.yaml into package.json. In their package.json, they have a dependency on the crypt3 package.

In the case of crypt3 (one of sinopia dependencies), check the [package.json](https://github.com/sendanor/node-crypt3/blob/master/package.json) . It contains

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node test/test.js",
    "install": "node-gyp rebuild"
  },
```

So, when sinopia is npm installed, it will download and install all if its dependencies as well. When crypt3 is installed, the "node-gyp rebuild" will be run, which is why you are seeing native c / c++ compile outputs in your console.

You can try it yourself by doing

```
npm install -g node-gyp && node-gyp rebuild
```

In the console

Comment: thanks. I saw the npm document saying 'install, postinstall: Run AFTER the package is installed.'. What does it mean by 'the package is installed'? I think the package is installed is equal to 'the package is downloaded'? right?

Comment: Kind of. npm will not automatically download any dependencies for a package, as you would end up having an infinite-length dependency tree. It will shrink-wrap the dependency for a module. That process of acknowledging a dependency, locating the right version and hooking it up with the module is the install process. The "install" and "post-install" scripts allow you to do something with your module while / after it is installed. It's only a hook to execute scripts at certain key moments of this process.

Answer (score 11):

The `g` in `npm install -g` is a flag signifying that you want to install that particular npm module system wide (globally). Without the `g` option, the module would be installed locally inside the current directory called `node_modules` -try it!

The location of your globally installed packages can vary depending on how you have installed node. Find out where they are installed by typing `npm list -g` in your command line.

edit: your error might be caused by insufficient privileges in your npm root directory, but it could also be that the version of node you're using is not supported by that library. Check which version of `node` you need to run `crypt3` and make sure your version of node matches that (`node -v`). If it does not match the required version, you can use a node version manager such as [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to switch to that version, and try `npm install` again.

Answer (score 4):

`npm install -g <package-name>` attempts to install the package into a system-wide node_modules directory (for Mac, this would be `"/usr/local/lib/node_modules"`)

Answer (score 0):

The **g** flag in `npm i -g <package-name>` states that, You do not have to install the specific package ever again because it just becomes a shared module of the node