# What exactly does 'npm install -g' without more arguments do?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I read `npm install -g` (note that **no** package name is specified) in a Dockerfile. What does it do?

My first guess is, it seems to install the current package (according to `./package.json` in current folder) as a global package

I see the following output:

```sh
npm install -g
```

```
+ some-package-name@0.19.0
added 1 package in 0.537s
```

Note: Not to be confused with this question with apparently similar title: [What exactly does 'npm install -g ' do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34408154/what-exactly-does-npm-install-g-do)
which is about `install -g <package-name>` with a specific package, which is not my question.

Comment: Is `some-package-name` mentioned in your `package.json`?

Comment: Not sure, sorry. This is an old question and I cannot check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install -g` will install the current package context (i.e. the current working directory) as a global package.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install